# How to update the value and recreate the array

Tags: html, angularjs

I fetch data from

```
$scope.roleinfo = {"QA":[{"White Box Testing":0},{"Black  Box 
Testing":0}],"Development":[{"Server Side":0},{"UI":0},{"Back end":0}]};
```

And displayed those value in table. Now I want to update maxcount and need to create array with keyvalue pair as below,

```
$scope.updatedmaxcount = {"QA":[{"White Box Testing":10},{"Black  Box   
Testing":20}],"Development":[{"Server Side":30},{"UI":5},{"Back end":10}]};
```

I have created a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29756/)

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more what you need to reach?

Comment: Can you give more details for what you want to achieve?

Comment: User can change maxcount values and after that i need to create an  array like {"QA":[{"White Box Testing":10},{"Black  Box   
Testing":20}],"Development":[{"Server Side":30},{"UI":5},{"Back end":10}]}; ( with the updated maxcount value). Maxcount value is white box testing, black box testing, serverside side and backend  values.

Comment: I need to create array when user click on save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using jquery with angular js.
i have updated you fiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29762/)

```
<input type="text" name="maxcount" class="form-control5" autocomplete="off" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" value="{{item[2]}}" id="newValue_{{$index}}">
```

i have just add id of all input with index and get value of input using his id.

> you need to add jquery in your code

Comment: Thanks this is I want.  
Sorry for asking again but the array is hardcoded. I need to get all table datas and recreate the array because all the datas are dynamic

Comment: i don't understand what you means.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, I think you just need to put "ng-model" in your input text control so that you will get the updated value in roleinfo object for whatever you will enter in the textbox.**

```
<input type="text" name="maxcount" class="form-control5" autocomplete="off" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-model="item[2]" value="{{item[2]}}">
```

**and now when you clicked out Save Button, then you can call a function there and if in that function you access your scope.info object then you will see the updated values in info object itself.**